# Proper stat for % error improvement of a classifier?

Tags: classification, error, model-evaluation

Question:
My intuition is that improving a binary classifier from 80% accuracy to 90% accuracy is similar in difficulty to improving from 90% to 95%, because both involve reducing the error rate by 50%.  Said another way: improving accuracy by 1% when your accuracy is only 60% is much easier than improving by 1% when your accuracy is 98%.  Is there a metric or branch of stats that deals with this sort of marginal error improvement?

My application: 
I have a set of classifiers that were trained with a different number of parameters.  I would like to know the marginal benefit of using more parameters.

Thanks for your help!